# How to select records based on max value of two fields as a subset of third field?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Given the following simple table:

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+----+
| id_ | match_op_id | bookie_id | version | p1 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+----+
|   1 |           1 |         1 |       1 |  1 |
|   2 |           1 |         2 |       1 |  5 |
|   3 |           1 |         1 |       2 |  3 |
|   4 |           1 |         2 |       2 |  4 |
|   5 |           2 |         1 |       1 |  5 |
|   6 |           2 |         2 |       1 |  3 |
|   7 |           2 |         2 |       2 |  4 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+----+
```

I want to build a query that selects the `match_op_id`, `bookie_id` and `p1` fields for a single record (doesn't matter which one) for each `match_op_id` from the max `version` of each `bookie_id` and then the max `p1`. So from the above I would get the output:

```
+-------------+-----------+----+
| match_op_id | bookie_id | p1 |
+-------------+-----------+----+
|           1 |         2 |  4 |
|           2 |         1 |  5 |
+-------------+-----------+----+
```

From the answer to another question I've got as far as:

```
SELECT o1.match_op_id, o1.bookie_id, MAX(o1.p1) p1
FROM odds_op o1
WHERE o1.version = (SELECT MAX(o2.version) FROM odds_op o2 WHERE o2.match_op_id = o1.match_op_id)
GROUP BY o1.match_op_id
```

However, I can't work out how to implement the max `version` by `bookie_id`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Edit:

To clear up a question raised in the comments... for each `match_op_id` I'm looking for the query to look for the highest `version` by `bookie_id` and then return the highest `p1`. So in the example above for `match_op_id` "2" then the max `version` for `bookie_id` "1" is "1" with a `p1` of "5". The max `version` for `bookie_id` "2" is "2" with a `p1` of "4". Therefore the query should return `bookie_id` "1" with a `p1` of "5".

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? The best answer depends on whether you can use window functions to run ranked queries.

Comment: Hi @BillKarwin - I've added the version. I want to take the resulting SQL and convert it into Python code and pretty sure I can't use window functions there

Comment: Isn't that rather 1,2,5 and 2,2,4 ?...

Comment: I've just added an answer, but I'm not sure if  `p1` must depend on `bookie_id` or not, given your question which might contains inaccuracies...

Comment: @St3an - apologies I've been away this week. The output above is correct as I'm looking for the query to look for the highest `version` by `bookie_id` and then return the highest `p1`. So in the example above for `match_op_id` "2" then the max `version` for `bookie_id` "1" is "1" with a `p1` of "5". The max `version` for `bookie_id` "2" is "2" with a `p1` of "4". Therefore the query should return `bookie_id` "1" with a `p1` of "5".

Comment: For bookie id 1, the highest version is 2 with the highest p1 = 3. It is difficult to understand the expected result.

Comment: @SalmanA - hi. If you're responding to my clarification above then I think you're referring to `match_op_id` "1" when the example I was giving was for `match_op_id` "2". The query needs to treat each `match_op_id` discretely when applying the max `version` / `p1` criteria. I've added in a clarification to the edit to make this clear.

Comment: so you need the max `bookie_id` by `match_op_id` too, right ?

Comment: @St3an - don't need max `bookie_id`. Need max `p1` for the max `version` by `bookie_id` by `match_op_id`

Comment: the max version by bookie_id by match_op_id : it will return more than two results

Comment: I've modified my answer accordingly, see

Comment: @St3an - thanks but as per the question I'm only looking to return one result

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer - again ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SQL

```
WITH max_versions AS
(SELECT match_op_id, bookie_id, MAX(version) AS version
 FROM tbl
 GROUP BY match_op_id, bookie_id),
mv_full AS
(SELECT t.match_op_id, t.bookie_id, t.p1
 FROM max_versions mv
 JOIN tbl t
   ON mv.match_op_id = t.match_op_id
  AND mv.bookie_id = t.bookie_id
  AND mv.version = t.version),
max_p1s AS
(SELECT match_op_id, MAX(p1) AS p1
 FROM mv_full
 GROUP BY match_op_id)
SELECT mf.*
FROM mv_full mf
JOIN max_p1s mp
ON mp.match_op_id = mf.match_op_id
AND mp.p1 = mf.p1
```

### Demo

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bb2df24dfdbf66e656c0736e7bd8aeb)

Comment: Thanks Steve! As per the comments I'm going to convert this code into Python via SQLAlchemy. I've had a look at `WITH` statements and they're a bit beyond me to engineer. Is there a way of solving this without them?

Comment: @Jossy Yes - anything that uses `WITH` statements is possible without but CTEs actually make things simpler and avoid repeated subselects. So would be a bit reluctant to convert unless there's good reason to (e.g. if a version of MySQL before 8 is being used, which am guessing isn't the case since mysql-8.0 was tagged).

Comment: Thanks Steve - guess I'd better roll my sleeves up then!

Comment: In case it helps I've updated the demo to include extra queries (+ comments) showing what each CTE is doing.

Comment: Thnaks Steve. I managed to get it all into Python on the first try :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT match_op_id, bookie_id, max_version, max_p1
FROM (
SELECT distinct st1.match_op_id match_op_id, st2.bookie_id, st2.max_version, st3.max_p1
        FROM SIMPLE_table st1
        JOIN ( -- version
        SELECT match_op_id, bookie_id, MAX(`version`) max_version FROM simple_table GROUP BY match_op_id, bookie_id) st2
        ON st1.match_op_id = st2.match_op_id
        JOIN ( -- p1
        SELECT match_op_id, bookie_id, `version`, MAX(p1) max_p1 FROM simple_table GROUP BY match_op_id, bookie_id, `version`) st3
        ON st2.max_version=st3.`version` AND st2.bookie_id=st3.bookie_id AND st1.match_op_id=st3.match_op_id) all_
GROUP BY max_version HAVING MAX(max_p1)
```

which gives :

```
"match_op_id"   "bookie_id" "max_version"   "max_p1"
"2"             "1"         "1"             "5"
"1"             "2"         "2"             "4"
```

Does that seem correct to you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function twice.
First use it to get the rows with the max `version` for each combination of `match_op_id` and `bookie_id` and then for the returned rows use it to get the for each `match_op_id` the row with the max `p1`:

```
SELECT match_op_id, bookie_id, p1
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id ORDER BY p1 DESC) rn2
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id, bookie_id ORDER BY version DESC) rn1
    FROM odds_op
  ) t  
  WHERE rn1 = 1
) t
WHERE rn2 = 1
```

Or with `ROW_NUMBER()` and `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT match_op_id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(bookie_id) OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id ORDER BY p1 DESC) bookie_id, 
       MAX(p1) OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id) p1
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match_op_id, bookie_id ORDER BY version DESC) rn
  FROM odds_op
) t  
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a25ca5226bc023aea718b929986d7982).
Results:

> | match_op_id | bookie_id | p1 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2 | 4 |
> | 2 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: Thanks for this. As per the comments I'm looking to eventually transfer the SQL to Python and I don't think SQLAlchemy supports window functions :-(

Comment: @Jossy I'm not an expert in SQLAlchemy but it seems like it supports window functions: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#window-functions

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. I've gone with the CTE approach for this question but marked your answer as definitely useful :-)